# Nuxt render function for a string of HTML that contains Vue components

Tags: vue.js, dom, render, nuxt.js

**I'm trying to solve this for Nuxt**

**Codesandbox of a WIP not working: https://codesandbox.io/s/zw26v3940m**

OK, so I have WordPress as a CMS, and it's outputting a bunch of HTML. A sample of the HTML looks like this:

```
'<h2>A heading tag</h2>
<site-banner image="{}" id="123">Slot text here</site-banner>
<p>some text</p>'
```

Notice that it contains a Vue component `<site-banner>` that has some props on it (the `image` prop is a JSON object I left out for brevity). That component is registered globally.

I have a component that we wrote, called `<wp-content>` that works great in Vue, but doesn't work in Nuxt. Note the two render functions, one is for Vue the other is for Nuxt (obviously this is for examples sake, I wouldn't use both).

```
export default {
    props: {
        html: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }
    },
    render(h, context) {
        // Worked great in Vue
        return h({ template: this.html })
    }      
    render(createElement, context) {
        // Kind of works in Nuxt, but doesn't render Vue components at all
        return createElement("div", { domProps: { innerHTML: this.html } })
    } 
}
```

So the last render function works in Nuxt except it won't actually render the Vue components in `this.html`, it just puts them on the page as HTML.

So how do I do this in Nuxt? I want to take a string of HTML from the server, and render it on the page, and turn any registered Vue components into proper full-blown Vue components. Basically a little "VueifyThis(html)" factory.

Comment: One idea I had was trying to turn the HTML "string" into just a JSX template (by removing the " from the string basically). But I'm not sure that's possible, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That exact function that works in Vue, doesn't it work in nuxt?

Comment: @acdcjunior no it doesn't in Nuxt 2.6.3

Comment: Did you add the ```nuxt.render``` to your app variables?

Comment: @jalil no I did not, what is that and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was what worked and was the cleanest, thanks to Jonas Galvez from the Nuxt team via [oTechie](https://otechie.com/nuxt/).

```
export default {
  props: {
    html: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h({
      template: `<div>${this.html}</div>`
    });
  }
};
```

Then in your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
    build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {
            // Include the compiler version of Vue so that <component-name> works
            config.resolve.alias["vue$"] = "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

And if you use the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive to render the html?

like:

```
<div v-html="html"></div>
```

I think it will do the job.

Comment: No, that won't unpack the Vue components unfortunately.

Comment: And if you use this one? https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wpcontent-j43sp

The main point is to wrap the dynamic component in a `<div>` (so an HTML tag) in the `dynamicComponent()` template, as it can only have one root element, and as it comes from Wordpress the source string itself can have any number of top level elements.

And the `WpContent` component had to be imported.

Comment: thanks for this example for me didn't work with 'vue-feather-icons' did you have any idea why?

Comment: What is exactly you were trying to do? Do you have your code online?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it with Nuxt 3 :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { h } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  class: string;
  HTML: string
}>();
const VNode = () => h('div', { class: props.class, innerHTML: props.HTML })
</script>
<template>
  <VNode />
</template>
```

There was not need to update `nuxt.config.ts`.
Hopefully it will help some of you.

Comment: Hm need to help with this, this is my no TS version

```
<template>
  <v-node />
</template>

<script setup>
import { h } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

const VNode = () =>
  h('div', { class: 'test-class', innerHTML: '<div>html test</div>' })
</script>
```

It gives me this error `VNode is not defined`, but it's definitely defined! Im using **Nuxt v2** with **@nuxtjs/composition-api**

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your codesandbox. seems work now https://codesandbox.io/s/q9wl8ry6q9

Things I changed that didn't work:

1. template can only has one single root element in current version of Vue
2. v-bind only accept variables but you pass in a string.